# Odoo REST API full response of relational model

Tags: node.js, rest, odoo-11

I used Node-Odoo library (https://github.com/isotopo/node-odoo) for CRUD operation on Odoo.

Below is code for fetch partner from Odoo.
 1. Connect with Odoo
 2. On success fetch partner with use of GET API

**Note: Backend library for API: https://github.com/isotopo/node-odoo/blob/master/lib/index.js**

// connection info: host(server url), port(80 & localhost port), database(db name),username & password of odoo server
    const odoo = new Odoo({
        host: localhost,
        port: 8069,
        database: db_name,
        username: admin,
        password: admin
    });

```
// connect to odoo
odoo.connect(function (err) {
    if(err){
        //if connection successfull then fetch partner
        odoo.get('res.partner', 1, function (err, partner) {
            // print partner response
                    console.log('partner',partner);
            });
    }
});
```

Its print below response(I am not put the full response here, show only highlighted fields)

```
[{
        "name": "ASUSTeK",

        "city": "Taipei",

        **"user_id": [1,"Girish"]**

}]
```

In above response object highlighted text '**user_id**' which have value '[1,"Girish"]',actually this field is relationship with '**res.users**' model. So problem is that Odoo returns only id & name of the user but not return a full object, so my question is that is Odoo have any setting or config for getting full response?.

Can anyone have a solution for get full object?.

**NOTE: I don't know it is Odoo default behavior or I can change it via any setting, No idea.**

Any solution or suggestion?.

Thank you

Comment: @JuanSalcedo here is a link: https://github.com/isotopo/node-odoo/blob/master/lib/index.js node library file which has CRUD operations code

Comment: Hi, @Girish, you should show a piece of your code at least, please take a look other question to get get a better understanding about how to publish a question or read the guidelines of stackoverflow.

Comment: @JuanSalcedo, sorry for the inconvenience. Now I hope provided info is helpful for the understanding question